# Regex for strings ending in .cs but not in .g.cs

Tags: .net, regex

I need a regex that matches all strings ending in .cs, but if they end in .g.cs they should not match. I'm using .NET regular expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will match the end if it's .cs but not .g.cs

```
(?<!\.g)\.cs$
```

For the entire string start to finish, something like this:

```
^.*(?<!\.g)\.cs$
```

Comment: whops yes, had a small tyop .? instead of .*, ungreedy shoulnd't matter though.

Answer (score 2):

In a regex engine without negative lookbehind:

```
^(.*[^g]|.*[^.]g|)\.cs$
```

Linguistically, general lookahead/lookbehind is non-regular, so it isn't a "regular expression" even though it's really convenient...

Irrelevant because you state that you're using .NET's regular expression engine, which supports non-regular extensions like this, but I like to make this point whenever I can.

Comment: Upvoted because this could be useful for people doing something similar in, say, JS.